# In Ocaml, how can I access the Lib module from the command line?

Tags: ocaml

If I type `ocaml` at the command line and then run code involving e.g. the `Lib.explode` function, I get the error `Error: Unbound module Lib`. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

You don't give much to go on. I assume `Lib` is not the real name, but just an example. You also don't say whether it's a standard OCaml library, a library you have built yourself, or somebody else's library.

Assume it's a library you have built yourself. Then somewhere you have a file named `lib.cmo` (for a single module) or `lib.cma` (for an archive of multiple modules). To use such a library from inside the OCaml REPL (the so-called "toplevel"):

```
$ ocaml
# #load "lib.cmo";;
```

Or:

```
$ ocaml
# #load "lib.cma";;
```

Note that you want to type `#load` including the `#`. The first `#` on the line is the prompt from OCaml. This sometimes makes it confusing to read a transcription of an OCaml session.

After loading the library you can refer to names in the library as you usually would, i.e., as `Lib.myfun`. You don't refer to them just by the name `myfun` (as it is sometimes tempting to assume).

Answer (score 2):

You may also wish to use `ocamlmktop`.

Consider for instance a very basic file `test.ml`:

```
let foo = 42
```

I compile that with the following and now have `test.cmo`.

```
ocamlc test.ml
```

Now I'll create a toplevel with that module available.

```
% ocamlmktop -o mytop test.cmo 
% ./mytop
        OCaml version 4.13.1

# Test.foo;;
- : int = 42
#
```